# IOException when attempting to connect to Solr using HTTPS

Tags: java, ssl, solr, https

Connecting to a Solr server using a http request was straightforward. But when I try to connect using a https request, I am getting errors.

Solr server: `https://localhost:8443/solr/#/`

I tried using solr api in java to connect to server with following code:

`SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("https://localhost:8443/solr/#/");`

But I got the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://localhost:8443/solr/#
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:413)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:181)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
at app.SolrQuerying.main(SolrQuerying.java:45)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:352)
... 4 more
```

If anyone has any solution to this, please share.

Comment: Have got solution ?  i have same problem .

Answer (score 1):

You error is show in the log here:

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException

What this is saying is that your SSL Certificate is not verified by a Certificate Authority, I am guessing you created a self signed certificate? Java by default will check for certificates that are verified by a Certificate Authority and error if not. The reason for this is security.

Look up how to use self-signed certificates with a Java Connection.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for you response.. i am new to solr . I have no idea about configuring and bypassing ssl certificate with this api. i want to show what i tried to do with ssl. if you have any idea please share.. thank you.
SolrServer server = new 

HttpSolrServer("'https://localhost:8443/solr/#/'");
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery().addNumericRangeFacet("Facility", 1, 1, 1);
query.setQuery( "Message:*DailyEvents_update.php*" );
        query.setFacet(true);
        query.setStart(0);
        query.setRows(100);

 QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
..

Comment: sorry it is SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("'https:\\localhost:8443/solr/#/'");

Comment: Have you got solution ?  i have same problem .